# can't see method content in java code

Tags: java

In a java class there are some methods like this. I don't get what exactly compiled code is. Can you explain what it is and what it is for?

```
private Severity(String newSeverityName) {
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
        /* 0: aload_0
         * 1: invokespecial #60                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         * 4: aload_0
         * 5: getstatic     #57                 // Field nextOrdinal:I
         * 8: dup
         * 9: iconst_1
         * 10: iadd
         * 11: putstatic     #57                 // Field nextOrdinal:I
         * 14: putfield      #58                 // Field ordinal:I
         * 17: aload_0
         * 18: aconst_null
         * 19: putfield      #59                 // Field severityName:Ljava/lang/String;
         * 22: aload_0
         * 23: aload_1
         * 24: putfield      #59                 // Field severityName:Ljava/lang/String;
         * 27: return
         *  */
        // </editor-fold>
    }
```

Comment: [Java byte code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) You get this in your IDE because the IDE don't have the source code available.

Comment: Further to @PeterMmm's comment, do you have the source code?

Comment: Do you want to know what the difference between source code and compiled code is? (If yes, try google!)

Comment: For me this looks like the syntetic constructor of an enum

Comment: @PeterMmm thank you very much. I think they want to hide their source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the java code, use JAva Decompiler (JAD).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcompiler/